Error: "Saving Prefab to immutable folder is not allowed" in Unity with Meta All-In-One SDK after setting up a fresh VR project
I am setting up a fresh Unity project for a VR project that uses Meta All-In-One SDK. To do this, I created a new 3D built-in render pipeline project, and I imported the Meta-All-In-One SDK (ver.68, but this happens with the 66 as well) from the Package Manager. After the package is imported, I fix and apply all the reccomended fixes, set up the build for Android, and select Oculus as XR plugin manager. Right after doing these operations, and as soon as I save the project, immediately an error pops up:
Saving Prefab to immutable folder is not allowed: Packages/com.meta.xr.sdk.interaction.ovr/Editor/Blocks/Interactors/Prefabs/[BB] Hand Ray.prefab
UnityEditor.EditorApplication:Internal_CallGlobalEventHandler ()


This happens mainly on these two objects: BB hand ray, and OVR camera rig interaction. Important to note is that no game objects or prefabs were added to the scene (that contains only Main Camera and Directional Light). This is a problem because is affecting the Build and Run operation, returning in errors when building Player.
I also had a try on another, more developed project, and this same error happens, but the Play mode with Quest Link is not affected at all and the app works perfectly, when not built. Does anybody have this same experience and problem? If so, does anyone came up with a solution?

You cant save into the packages folder. Only the assets folder

hey, thanks for the reply! I am not saving "into" the Packages folder. I just create a project, without adding anything, and save the project.

Any chance its saving into a onedrive area ?

Oh dear, I'm almost sure it's not haha. I will make sure of this. Thanks btw

Packages installed via the Package Manager are read-only. If you want to modify a prefab from the package, make a copy and it will be placed in the Assets folder.

I replied to your comment in the forums but for visibility is probably also good to answer you here.
I came across this issue recently too when using Unity 2022.3.0.
I believe the faulty piece is the Unity component SortingGroup within the [BB] Hand Ray prefab. I inspected the Unity changelong and it looks like this bug could cause it: https://issuetracker.unity3d.com/issues/gameobjects-with-sortinggroup-is-dirty-after-loading
I updated my project to the latest Unity 2022.3.46f and could successfully build.
Please let me know which version were you using and if this fixes your problem!
